# Android Clickable Listview (when clicked show another activity)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener, clickable

I have a custom listview with image title and description.
I want every row show custom activity for example see this pic ->

[image: x]

Here is the [link][1] to my project ANDROID STUDIO.

I'm trying this almost for 2 weeks everyday searching but didn't find anything

Comment: It's better to post some code here instead of link to other places. by the way, as I can say with this information you should use `onClickListener` and `Intent`.

Comment: can you post the ListView code...

Comment: Override `onListItemClick()` and use an `Intent` to start the second Activity.

Comment: im really beginner i will post code right now

Answer (score 0):

Create new ActivtityB .Looking at your Code just put the following code in MainActivity.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(Adapter adapter,View view,int position,long id){
Intent i =new Intent(this,ACTIVITYB.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```